# Reactjs - Flux - Component is subscribing to event even before its loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, reactjs-flux, refluxjs

**I am using ReactJS with flux**. All the pages in my application have subscribed to a event name `FilterChange`.

You will see this kind of code in all of the pages.

```
componentWillMount() {
    StateActions.addFilterListener(this._filterListener);
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
     StateActions.removeFilterListener(this._filterListener);
  }
```

Consider this scenario.

We have to pages: Page A and page B.

When we click on a button on Page A, we fire `FilterChange` event and all those who have subscribed to this event, they respond to it.

**Clicking on button on page A takes to Page B & here page B also responds to `FilterChange`. This is the part I do not understand.**

When event was fired on Page A, page B was not even loaded & its `componentWillMount` code was not executed which means, it has not subscribed to `FilterChange` yet. **Then why page B is responding to FilterChange event ?**

Comment: does componentwillmount work after B responds to filter change event?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @VikramSaini: I cannot share the code. Creating a fiddle is not easy as it requires full flux setup. When the page B load, it responds to `FilterChange` event (which is what I don't want) & when user change any filter while on page B, page B does respond to filter change event, which is correct.

Comment: add condition before subscribe. ```if(isMounted) {  StateActions.addFilterListener(this._filterListener); }```

Comment: @ReiDien: check this link: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html   . And even if I use isMounted property, I don't know how it will help in my case.